# How to run a project based on Prism MVVM in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have the scenario as there are four projects named as

1. Freedom.Composite.Core
2. Freedom.Composite.Styles(Catalogs,Commands,Converters,LoggerComponents,LoggersViewModelHelper)
3. Freedom.Core.XmlSerializers(Different Styles of the UI)
4. SyncDash(There are views into it.The )

When I execute these project it prompts me:

> "A project with output type of class library could not be started
>   directly.
>
> In orderto debug these project,add an executable project to
>   this solution which references the library project.Set the executable
>   project as the startup project."

So for this I have made a hello world project referring the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141(v=pandp.40).aspx

So got it from the sample Application that it is the 'Bootstrapper that loads the projects'.

So when I run the Solution It gives me an Activation Exception....I really need to run this solution on a high priority...Please help me .....

Comment: can you show the bootstrapper code here?

Comment: Where's the executable?  You need an executable.  This is not even.  You have to have a wpf application project.  Why would you even think that running a DLL would work?  How would it even run?  What are you doing? If you know nothing, then it doesn't matter what priority you have, because you will be unable to DO anything.

Comment: Hi Sameer, I wrote the Freedom framework. Please contact me privately, the guys you work with have my details.